# Jquery check if multiple drop down list has any selected option

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to display in console a message when a user removes all options from a multiple drop down list. My current code creates a JSON object when there are options selected and encodes the items into a URI string component.

How can I display a message when the user removes all selected options?

```
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Customer</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <select id="Customers" class="js-select2-custom custom-select" name="CustomerID" multiple size="1" style="opacity: 0;" asp-for="CustomerID" onchange="getSelects()"
                                            data-hs-select2-options='{
                                           "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity"
                                         }'>
                                        @{
                                            var selectedCustomer = Model.CustomerList.Where(x => Model.SelectedCustomers.Any(c => c.CustomerID == x.CustomerID));
                                            var Customers = Model.CustomerList.Where(x => !Model.SelectedCustomers.Any(c => c.CustomerID == x.CustomerID));
                                        }
                                        @foreach (var item in selectedCustomer)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.CustomerID" selected>@item.CustomerName</option>
                                        }
                                        @foreach (var item in Customers)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.CustomerID">@item.CustomerName</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


        function getSelects() {
        $('#selectedText').val('');
        var items = $("#Customers > option:selected").map(function () {
            var opt = {};
                 $('#Customers > option:selected').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).not(':selected')) {
                        alert('Yes')
                    }
                });
            return opt;
        }).get();

        $('#selectedText').val(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(items)));
        console.log($('#selectedText').val());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Press and hold the "Ctrl" key to select/deselect multiple:

```js
$('#cars').change(function(){
  
  // get selected values:
  var values = $(this).val();
  console.log('selected values: ', values);
  
  // send alert if none are selected:
  if (!values.length) alert('No values selected!');  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```